# Why use a Microtask in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I'm learning Flutter and recently found Microtasks. I've read up on it and I understand what Microtasks are and what the Microtask queue is, but am still a little confused why I'd ever use one.

I'd appreciate an real-world example or explanation of when/why to use a Microtask.

Thanks.

Comment: real-world examples? check flutter sources then, for example lib/src/widgets has 9 places where `scheduleMicrotask` is used - most of them with a comment why it is used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a concrete example I found usefull to understand it. Some operation while the widget tree is building are forbidden. Most of the time it is used in `initState`

Consider you are using the [provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

```
initState() {
  super.initState();
  context.read<MyNotifier>().fetchSomething(); // -> not work
}
```

Actually `fetchSomething()` will call a http package to get data and some stuff. This is not allowed because the state update is synchronous and here there is a lap of time during the value (new/old) can change (here before and after the data loaded from http).

**This could cause inconsistencies in your UI and is therefore not allowed.**

A workaround is to use a microtask to achieve it. This will schedule it to happen on the next async task cycle (i.e. after build is complete here).

```
initState() {
  super.initState();
  Future.microtask(() =>
    context.read<MyNotifier>().fetchSomething(someValue); --> this work
  );
}
```

To sum up this example, Microtask is usually created if we need to complete a task later, but before returning control to the event loop.

Comment: Learned something new 